# Finding the partial derivatives of $f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3+3x^2y+3y^2x+3xz^2+x^2y^2z^2$

Tags: partial-derivative

Would someone be able to explain the concept of implicit partial differentiation, I understand the concepts of basic partial differentiation and implicit differentiation but not partial implicit differentiation.

As an example to explain it would someone be able to help me find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} and \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x \partial y \partial z}$

$f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3+3x^2y+3y^2x+3xz^2+x^2y^2z^2$

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: I don't see anything implicit there. Ordinary partial differentiation (which you understand) is all you need.

Comment: Could you show me it for one of them then as I'm not seeing it

Comment: Perhaps you're unsure what is meant by the third-order partial derivative you're asked to find. If that's so: $\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x\,\partial y\,\partial z}=\frac\partial{\partial x}\left[\frac\partial{\partial y}\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right]\right]$

Comment: The last term in the partial derivative with respect to $x$ is $2xy^2z^2$ since you think of $y$ and $z$ as constant. You can do the other terms the same way. That's "basic partial differentiation" which you say you understand.

Comment: So, to partially differentiate to the respect of a variable means you differentiate any term that contains that variable while treating other variables as constants.


Looking at your example then; we have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3x^2+6xy+3y^2+3z^2+2xy^2z^2.$$ With this in mind, try doing the others.

Comment: Hint for computing the 3rd-order derivative: there’s only one term that contains all three variables.